# How do boundary layers and shocks interact?

Tags: aerodynamics, supersonic, fluid-mechanics, shock-waves, boundary-layer

How do boundary layers and shocks interact? What difference is made with thinner and thicker BL's? I've recently been researching this topic, but at least for me there are no good search results on google.

(I am aware that this is a very complex subject, and I do not have that much intuition about this subject so far, so take that as you will. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a topic that you are going to find elementary resources to hold your hand.  This is a topic that is studied by graduate and professional engineers.  This is not a topic covered in an undergraduate Aerospace Engineering curriculum.  Consequently, there is no market for plain language textbooks on the subject.  This is an advanced subject and the materials you find are going to be accordingly advanced.

The first results when I google 'shock boundary layer interaction' are all very promising.  If you aren't up to the task of reading a detailed technical paper -- then you aren't up to the task about learning about shock / boundary layer interaction.

Comment: Yeah I was aware that this was a complex subject, but I didn't know it was a whole different field of 'fluid studies', so to speak. I think I'll hold off on this subject, as it doesn't really seem to follow my interest in aerodynamics.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer 